# Javascript executing multiple ajax calls in seq each returning a bool

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to execute three similar ajax calls in order whilst returning a Boolean for each.

Example Below

```
function Request(){

var _req1_successful = false;
var _req2_successful = false;
var _req3_successful = false;

_req1_successful = RequestCall(**params**)
_req2_successful = RequestCall(**params**)
_req3_successful = RequestCall(**params**)

**Carry out results etc...**
}

function RequestCall(**Params**) {
 $.ajax({"URL",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: "{**Params**}",
        success: function(data) {
           return true 
        },
        error: function(x, e) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I've looked at callback's but either i'm missing something or you cant return values using them. (Forgive if incorrect im fairly new to JS)

I read adding a `Aysnc="False"` property to the ajax call would work but didn't seem to...

So in a nutshell im trying to execute each call sequentially then once all has been carried out execute the logic afterwards.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Your `RequestCall()` function isn't returning anything as the AJAX call is asynchronous (it's what the 'A' stands for). You need to use the clalback pattern properly. See the duplicate for more information.

Comment: [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [async/await](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9)

Comment: The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, you can use async await